# Dual boot Linux partition scheme with encryption

Tags: partition, dual-boot, encryption, disk-encryption

I am trying to figure out how I should encrypt my machine.  I am reorganizing and will have two 500GB drives. I am setting up a dual boot system (both linux).

My prospective partition scheme:

sda:

- `/boot`
- `/swap` [encrypted]
- `/[file system #1 - Xubuntu]` [encrypted]
- `/[file system #2 - Crunchbang]` [encrypted]
- `/home` [encrypted]
- `/data1` [encrypted]

sdb:

- `/data2` [encrypted]

the encryption schemes I’ve been looking at (dm-crypt and/or ecryptfs) are:

sda:

- `/boot`
- `/VLM` [dm-crypt]

  - swap
  - `[file system #1 - Xubuntu]`
  - `[file system #2 - Crunchbang]`
  - `/home`
  - `/data`

sdb:

- `/data2` [dm-crypt]

or

sda:

- `/boot`
- `/swap` [dm-crypt]
- `/file system #1` [dm-crypt]
- `/file system #2` [dm-crypt]
- `/home`

  - /home/xubuntu [ecryptfs]
  - /home/crunchbang [ecryptfs]
- `/data1` [dm-crypt]

sdb:

- `/data2` [dm-crypt]

I want decryption of the sub-LVM disk (or individual file system depending on the case) encryption to trigger decryption of both home directories and the data partitions. encrypting with LVM would nead just one encrypt hook for the sdb encryption I suppose.

Does one align more with best practices?